# Discrete fourier transform with irreducible $k$ points

Tags: computational-physics, fourier-transform, crystals

Not sure if this is the right forum to ask but gonna take the chance. I'd like to numerically do discrete Fourier transforms with irreducible $\bf k$ points in a Brillouin zone but, it seems that with this set of irreducible $\bf k$ points I can't get the same consistent values of the original function after FT-ing back to the real-space. Let me describe the problem in more details: Let's say I start with a function $f(\bf R)$ then I FT to the $\bf k$-space with a given set of irreducible $\bf k$ points:

$$F ({\bf k}) = \sum_{\bf{R} } \exp(i{\bf k} \cdot {\bf R})\ f({\bf R})\ .$$

Then, I transform back $F({\bf k})$ into the real-space:

$$ \tilde f ({\bf R}) = \sum_{\bf{k} } w_{\bf k}\exp(-i{\bf k} \cdot {\bf R})\ F({\bf k})\ .$$

Here, $\sum_{\bf k} w_{\bf k} = 1$. The problem is that for each ${\bf R}$, $f({\bf R}) \neq \tilde f({\bf R})$. This problem doesn't happen when I use the full (i.e. reducible) $\bf k$ points. But FTs with the full $\bf k$ points are not so efficient. I'm sure this is merely a numerical issue, but I have no clue how to fix it. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "irreducible"? If you mean breaking up a regular square array to get rid of points, the loss of the FFT is likely to kill any other performance gains you'll make on the order reduction. However, there isn't enough context to tell.

Comment: Irreducible $\bf k$ points are the ones from irreducible Brillouin zone; i.e. the first Brillouin zone reduced by all of the symmetries in the point group of the lattice (point group of the crystal).

Comment: Is this an undersampling problem?  If there is aliasing, it is impossible to recover the original $f(\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I'm not sure I understand what you mean by aliasing but I don't think it's an under-sampling problem.

Comment: The irreducible Brillouin zone (IBZ) is still a continuous region of space. So to perform a discrete FT one would need to sample the space inside the IBZ. Is this what you do? This sampling can have all sorts of effects. Is it a 2D or 3D space?

Comment: @flippiefanus The set of irreducible $\bf k$ points were obtained from a density-functional-theory (DFT) calculation, and in that calculation, the set has been tested to give a converged result. So, I'm sure the sampling isn't the problem. I just want to know how in a DFT program generally does the FT with irreducible $\bf k$ points without getting into this numerical accuracy problem, like my "naive" calculation have.

Comment: Just an idea: could you have gotten the IBZ wrong? Can this be checked by some numerical experiment like acting with the transformations on the k-points in the IBZ? You might also want to try posting this on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is known that under certain conditions, when one performs a FFT of a function and then do an iFFT one does not get back the same function. However, it is difficult for me to determine whether these conditions would be valid in this case.